# node serialport not displaying serialport data in raspberryPI

Tags: node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi, node-serialport

I am trying to read the serialport data coming from Arduino to Raspberry PI but it doesn't display anything. I have verified that the data is arriving in the serialport. The same script works fine in windows 7. Also I have tried two different approaches of reading the serial data but none of them work.
The node.js version I am using is v0.9.9.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var sys = require('sys');
var portName = '/dev/ttyACM0' ;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Approach 1
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, {
     baudrate: 9600
   });

serialPort.on("open", function () {
console.log('open');
serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
//console.log('data received: ' + data);
sys.puts("here: "+data);
});

serialPort.on('error', function(message) {
console.log('error: ' + message);
});
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Approach 2 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort; // localize object constructor

var sp = new SerialPort(portName, { 
     parser: serialport.parsers.raw
     });

sp.on("data", function (data) {
sys.puts("here: "+data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see if it is a linux permission thing.

Have you installed it on you linux machine?

```
nmp install serialport
```

Could you answer a question for me. Why are you using javascript to read from a serial port?

[Serial port not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902704/serial-port-on-node-not-working-s)

[Can't install node-serialport on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549304/cant-install-node-serialport-on-linux)

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the reply. It cannot be linux permission issue because I have a python script which can read the serial port without any problem. I have used the same command to install serialport -nmp install serialport. The reason why I am using javascript is I have created a website which is developed using node.js and it fits well with serialport. Earlier I have used serialport2 to do the same thing and it used to work perfectly. But serialport2 is merged with serialport and I cant get it work.

Comment: "npm install serialport" is a good prerequisite. Never forget it. I did :(

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data are you sending with your Arduino?
The best approach would be to jsonize all your data and parse them once in node.

Here is an example for Arduino I'm using, you can modify it to suit your needs:

```
void sendJson(){
    String json;

    json = "{\"accel\":{\"x\":";
    json = json + getXYZ(0);
    json = json + ",\"y\":";
    json = json + getXYZ(1);
    json = json + ",\"z\":";
    json = json + getXYZ(2);
    json = json + "},\"gyro\":{\"yaw\":";
    json = json + getYPR(0);
    json = json + ",\"pitch\":";
    json = json + getYPR(1);
    json = json + ",\"roll\":";
    json = json + getYPR(2);
    json = json + "}}";

    Serial.println(json);
}
```

Then in node, it's quite easy:

```
serialPort.on("data", function (data) {
    json = JSON.parse(data.replace(/ /g,""));
    AccelX = json.accel.x;
    // and so on.
});
```

Hope it helps!